# I revoked distribution certificate but I can not create new one

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-developer

In my developer account I have 3 distribution certificates (*For use with Xcode 11 or later*). I changed my workstation and I lost all private keys so I revoked one of the certificates to generate a new one, but the account still shows **"Maximum number of certificates generated"**.

Is this normal? and what I have to do in order to generate new certificate?

Comment: Revoke all of them? I'm surprised you were able to create three in the first place.

Comment: @matt The maximum number of certificates is 3: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8

Answer (score 0):

For sure you need to remove some to be able to generate new ones. Restart Xcode to avoid issue if you want to do it automatically. Anyway, you can always generate it manually through developer portal website.